# How to form a variable name dynamically by concatenating two strings in JS, to form the name of my Google Map Marker variable?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a `<script type="text/javascript">` included in my web page. This script is defining **`Markers`** for my Google Map among other things. There is another script included in this page which is referenced from another `.js` file. I need to, in the second script written in the separate JS file, change icons of markers dynamically, based on some condition.

Actually in the first page, I read data from a database table using PHP. Then use this data to write PHP statements like

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'function initMap() {';
//.... code code
echo 'var marker'. $recordIdFromDb .' = new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat: '.$recordData["lat"].', lng: '.$recordData["lng"].'}, map:map, icon: greenIcon});';
```

Let's say the last statement in the above PHP code prints into the web page:

```
var markerXYZ123 = new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:123, lng:456}, map:map, icon: greenIcon})
```

Now, in the second script, I am doing some processing, as a result of which I first update some fields in the records of the database table which was the source of the data in the above mentioned first script.

Then, in the second script, I pull data from the same data table. Then, on the basis of some condition, I have to change the icon of the marker. For that I will have to use a statement like

```
markerXYZ123.setIcon(blah blah);
```

Now as noted above, `XYZ123` suffix of the marker's name is actually the `id` of this record from the database. **In the second script, I have this `id`. I need to dynamically form the name of the marker variable. Something like**

```
("marker" + "XYZ123").setIcon(blah blah);
```

How do I do that? How do I dynamically form this variable name, in Javascript?

Comment: Dynamic variable names are a huge code smell. Use an object instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance "Use an object instead." - I'm a newbie. Can you explain a little bit more, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object indexed by `id` instead of a dynamic variable name. For example, in your first script:

```
const markers = {};
markers[<?= $recordIdFromDb; ?>] = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: <?= $recordData["lat"] ?>,
    lng: <?= $recordData["lng"] ?>,
  },
  map,
  icon: greenIcon,
});
```

Then in your other script, just use the `recordIdFromDb` that you have again to access the appropriate key in the `markers` object:

```
markers["XYZ123"].setIcon(...
```

Comment: Hi, I get an error in the second `.js` file when I try to access the markers object: **Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined**

Comment: Make sure to define `markers` in the *global scope* so that you can access it from your other script, otherwise you'll get a `ReferenceError`